# Can the spell component for the Summon Draconic Spirit spell be also used for the Fizban's Platinum Shield spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The description of the *Summon Draconic Spirit* spell lists the following components (FTD, p. 21; emphasis mine):

> Components: V, S, **M** (an object with the **image of a dragon** engraved on it, **worth at least 500 gp**)

The description of the *Fizban's Platinum Shield* spell lists the following components (FTD, p. 20; emphasis mine):

> Components: V, S, **M** (a platinum-plated **dragon scale**, **worth at least 500 gp**)

To me, these two spells list components materials that seem similar and interchangeable.

The material components for both spells really caught my attention. That is why I ask:

**Can the spell component for the *Summon Draconic Spirit* spell be also used for the *Fizban's Platinum Shield* spell?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes, as long as the platinum-plated scale has the image of a dragon engraved on it.

Both spells require components with the same value, and a platinum-plated scale is certainly "an object". So a platinum-plated scale with an image of a dragon engraved on it fulfills the requirements of both spells.

That said, acquiring such components falls with in the DM's purview, you will have to ask them about how you might acquire such a finely crafted scale.

Answer (score 6):

### The scale by itself is not sufficient

The requirement asks for an object with the **image of a dragon** engraved that is **worth 500 gp**. Literally *any* object that is worth 500 gp, including a scale, will work as long as it has an image of a dragon engraved.

However, the scale *by itself*, even though it is a dragon-related object and does satisfy the value requirement, *does not have an image of a dragon* engraved, and therefore *would not satisfy the requirement*.

Dragon armor and scales are known to be extremely hard, and [scale armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-scale-mail) fashioned from it counts as a magic item. The scale itself however would not be magical. If you already own one, then a skilled armorer or engraver would be able to embellish it with the engraving.

If you do not own the scale, any object that is worth more than 500 gp and that can be engraved, such as art objects or gems, could work as a basis to be enhanced. Such items may be unavailable in small villages, and maybe even towns, but unless the world you play in is very unusual, they would be readily available in a city. For practical purposes of weight reduction for carrying the component, a valuable gem engraved by a gem cutter might be a good option.